# Proving Non-Concreteness of a Category

Tags: category-theory

So, since I've just accidentally stumbled onto the topic of non-concrete (*inconcrete?*) categories, I've been looking around for some simple examples that did not even make use of such things as elements, and on the blog [*Mathematics Prelims*](https://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/concrete-and-non-concrete-categories-informally/), I found a rather neat example:

[image: Non-Concrete Category]

> There are, of course, categories which are not concrete.  In the last post we saw a very simple category with three objects.  These objects aren’t sets, they’re just “things” that we decided to label A, B, and C.  The morphisms between these objects aren’t functions in any sense of the word: they don’t associate inputs with outputs, there aren’t even any “inputs” or “outputs” to speak of!  Our morphisms are literally just arrows that start at one object and end at another.  (For this reason some people simply refer to the morphisms of a category as arrows.)

Well, only thing that bothers me now is my head goes around in circles as I try to figure out how to definitively prove that you can **not** construct a faithful functor from this category to **Set**.

Anyone willing to help satisfy my urge for completeness on this matter?

Look forward to your responses.

Comment: Every *small* category can be realized as a concrete category. Though the given category is not concrete as it is, it can be made so.

Comment: The simplest example of a category that is provable non-concrete, for what it's worth, is a category of topological spaces and homotopy classes of maps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*There is an important terminological discrepancy here: some authors use the term "concrete" for what others refer to as "concret**izable**" (see e.g. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category) versus [Freyd](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6.pdf)). After a certain amount of exposure, this discrepancy is fairly benign, but initially it can be confusing. Contra the original version of this answer, I'll follow the nLab language.*

---

Despite the name, a concrete category isn't just a category - it's a category *together with* a particular faithful functor into **Sets**. A concret*izable* category, meanwhile, is a category such that there exists such a functor (but we don't pick out a specific one).

So the linked post is **correct** in claiming that the category in question is not a concrete category - for the silly reason that it's just a category, as opposed to a category + a specific faithful functor into **Sets**. On the other hand, it's easy to show that it *is* concretizable.

- It's worth observing that **all non-concretizable categories are pretty complicated** (and in particular, all small categories are concretizable).

That said, the post linked is *still* slightly imprecise when it comes to defining concrete categories:

> [C]oncrete categories [...] **are** categories where the objects are sets, usually with some additional structure (group structure, a topology, etc.), and the morphisms are well-defined functions between those sets that preserve the structure.

*(Emphasis mine.)* The bolded "are" isn't really accurate; rather, a concrete category is intuitively a category together with an "interpretation" of the objects and morphisms as sets and functions. But the objects aren't required to literally *be* sets, they just need to *correspond* to sets in some explicit way (namely, via a specific choice of faithful functor).

Comment: Well this is most embarrassing, but I'm pretty glad we got this sorted out this early. Thank you.

Comment: @StormyTeacup I don't think the article is wrong. A concrete category is usually defined to be a category *equipped with* a faithful functor to set; pair $(\mathbf C, U)$ where $\mathbf C$ is a category and $U:\mathbf C\to\mathbf{Set}$ is a faithful functor. It's not merely a $\mathbf C$ such that some such $U$ *exists*. We actually demand the choice of a particular $U$, which is essentially the same as saying that the objects must be sets and the morphisms must be (distinct) functions.

Comment: With all due respect, Mr. Cunningham, this seems to me a somewhat *metaphysical distinction* that is beyond my grasp. XD Care to elaborate further for the benefit of a newbie like me?

Comment: @OscarCunningham That's not universal - see e.g. the usage in the paper [Homotopy is not concrete](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6.pdf).

Comment: @OscarCunningham I've edited to clarify this point.

Comment: @StormyTeacup See my edit - there's a bit of a terminological discrepancy at work here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well that clear it up! Was beginning to feel a bit like a 'Who's On First?' routine, but now there's no confusion or ambiguities left. :)

Answer (score 5):

Call this category $\mathbf{C}$. Then, there are lots of functors from $\mathbf{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$, and they are all faithful because $\mathbf{C}$ is a poset.

Comment: So, **C** is concrete? That’s annoying.

Answer (score 3):

The naive homotopy category of pointed topological spaces is not conrete. Here is how we construct it: $\textbf{Top}_*$ is the category of pointed topological spaces and continuous basepoint preserving functions between them.

Let $\text{NH}(\textbf{Top}_*)$, the naive homotopy category of pointed topological spaces be the category with the same objects as $\textbf{Top}_*$ but the hom sets $\text{Hom}_{\text{NH}(\textbf{Top})}((A,a),(B,b))$ are pointed homotopy classes of maps $(A,a) \rightarrow (B,b)$. I.e two maps are in the same class if there is a pointed homotopy between them.

Basic homotopy theory tells us that the usual composition of maps gives a well defined composition of maps on homotopy classes. I.e if we let $[f]$ be the set of pointed homotopy classes then the operation $[f] \circ[g] = [f \circ g]$ is well defined.

The proof that $\text{NH}(\textbf{Top}_*)$ is not concrete is complicated but you can read it [here](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/homotopy-is-not-concrete/)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of things that are naturally categories, but do not have a canonical way to be embedded in Set (here I am taking concrete not as concretizable, but equipped with a specific faithful functor to Set).

- Take a graph and consider the free category generated by this graph, i.e. the objects are vertices of the graph, and the arrows are paths from one vertex to another in your graph. This is a perfectly fine category, which is not concrete. This leads to my favorite example: starting from the graph of the metro in New York (or anywhere you want). The objects are literally metro stations, and the morphisms are metro trips... This is both very natural and as far from sets as I can imagine
- In type theory, we look at the syntactic category associated to a theory, where the objects are contexts and the morphisms are substitutions. They don't look like sets
- When you define a monoid as a one object category, the only object that you consider has nothing to do with sets a priori

So I am aware that these examples may be concretizable, but I like the fact that they appear really naturally and are not at all formulated with sets.